# What's the best way to build a track selector?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm building a new terminal for my minecart tracks:

[image: Minecart Tracks]

Currently there are 8, I may add more later. What I'd like to add is a single arrival/departure track, with buttons to select destination. Pressing the button would switch the track layout to connect the departure track to the correct outgoing track. Ideally, arrivals would all be routed to the same spot, but that's of less importance.

What's the best way to implement this? I want a layout that's reasonably compact, and extensible, and doesn't rely on bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Minecraftaddict*](http://www.youtube.com/user/Minecraftaddict) has a series of tutorials on how to build minecart stations with multiple destinations. The episode included below showcases how you can use RS-NOR latches to change destinations.

The basic principle is that the main destination line must branch off onto various destination tracks, and these tracks are selected by Redstone Torches toggling on and off.

Also, [TaviRider](http://www.youtube.com/TaviRider) came up with an ingenious way to make a track selector for a minecart station. The design is extremely compact, and surprisingly, all the inputs all use the same input line.

Comment: I'll attempt to put a brief tutorial in this answer as well.

Comment: I'm working on a similar implementation using RS NOR latches. I think mine is a bit smaller, I'll post when it's done.

Comment: Worked brilliantly, here's the finished system. I had to add a few repeaters to make this design stretch to 8, but it worked fine: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MW1x88gMhU

Comment: @fredley Very nice station! I'm glad it worked.